# How can I fix this function to make it read a string passed by the user as a path and not as something else on python? tkinter related

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, tkinter, path, tkinter-text

I developed a program that will ask the user for the `Profile Path` of Chrome Browser (it can be obtained by typing `chrome://version/` in the address bar of Chrome Browser), the user will have to copy and paste that path in to the `data_input` entry, and then click on the `user_data` button to continue with the process, here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk #for user inputs
from tkinter import messagebox #for warning messages 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400') #resolution
root.title("Bulkdozer") #Name of this program
root.attributes('-topmost', True) #keep the program's window top-most


def submit_profile_path():
    if len(profile_path.get()) == 0: #check if the user didn't type anything and pressed the button 
        messagebox.showerror(message="You didn't provide any input, try again", title="NULL Input")
    elif len(profile_path.get()) > 0:
        if r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get() == True: #check if the path provided by the user is a valid one
            if profile_path.get().split("User Data\\",1)[1] != None: #now check if at the end of that path exist an actual profile folder
                user_data.pack_forget() #hide the user_data button
                data_input.pack_forget() #hide the data_input
                profile_path_label.pack_forget() #hide the profile_path_label
                print(profile_path.get())
                open_browser.pack() #show the open_browser button
                
            else: #inform the user that he must provide the profile path containing the corresponding profile folder
                messagebox.showwarning(message="You forgot to add the profile folder in the profile path, try again", title="Profile Folder Missing")
                data_input.delete(0, tk.END)        
                
        else: #inform the user that he must provide a valid profile path
            messagebox.showwarning(message="The path provided does not seem to be the right one, try again", title="Invalid Profile PATH")
            data_input.delete(0, tk.END)
            
# BUTTON FOR PROVIDING THE PROFILE PATH OF CHROME BROWSER #
profile_path = tk.StringVar() #This variable will be used for storing the profile path string passed by the user
signin = ttk.Frame(root) #create a container for variable profile path
signin.pack(padx=55, pady=20, fill='x', expand=True) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this container
profile_path_label = ttk.Label(signin, text="Introduce YOUR profile path:") #create a label for the profile_path variable
profile_path_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True) #add the label
data_input = ttk.Entry(signin, textvariable=profile_path) #create an entry for the profile_path variable
data_input.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
data_input.focus()
user_data = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Submit User Data", command=submit_profile_path) #executes the function when clicked
user_data.place(x=60, y=40, width=100, height=30) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this button
user_data.pack() #Apply The Pack geometry manager to this button for using its functions later on
```

**GUI preview:**

[image: Preview1]

However, **it's not working as expected** because even though the user provides exactly the right `Profile Path`, after pressing the `user_data` button, the function `submit_profile_path()` will always execute the condition `messagebox.showwarning(message="The path provided does not seem to be the right one, try again", title="Invalid Profile PATH")` as shown down below:

[image: problem preview]

Which **should not be the case** because I set the condition `if r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get() == True:`, meaning that if the path provided by the user contains `\Google\Chrome\User Data`, it should then verify that there's a folder name after the string `User Data\\` (which in my case is Default), and then execute the rest of the code.

I would like to know what else is missing in my code above in order to work as expected? (i.e. execute the condition `if profile_path.get().split("User Data\\",1)[1] != None:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In general, you usually don't want to compare `== True` except in very special circumstances
- In Python in particular `r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get() == True` is equivalent to `r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get() and profile_path.get() == True` (except the `.get()` is only called once); this is clearly not what you intended

To fix this, omit the `== True`

`if  r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get():`

Comment: Oh okay, now I see it. Thank you! Do you also know if there's another of way of evaluating if there's a string after ``User Data\\`` ? I ask this because I tested the `else` condition to make sure it would execute if I provided a path like this one ``C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`` but it didn't, it kept executing the ``profile_path.get().split("User Data\\",1)[1] != None`` condition...

Comment: In a split like that, you wouldn't get `None`, you'd get the empty string `""`

Comment: More generally, have a read through the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?